How to sort values in group_concat()
I tried to sort a group_concat list but keeping getting error. Below is what I've tried. If someone can please help.
eg.
customer order_id  status
ABC      1234      1
ABC      1235      5
DEF      1236      1
DEF      1237      5

Script used:
GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(status AS STRING), ', ') AS status

result:
 customer   status
 ABC        1, 5
 DEF        5, 1

but would like the result to return the following:
 customer   status
 ABC        1, 5
 DEF        1, 5

Tried the following script but keep getting error msg:
GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(status AS STRING), ', ' ORDER BY status) AS status_ordered,


All you need is the order by, You can try this code example.
WITH SortedStatus AS (
    SELECT 
        customer, 
        SORT_ARRAY(COLLECT_LIST(CAST(status AS STRING))) AS sorted_status
    FROM 
        your_table_name
    GROUP BY 
        customer
)

SELECT 
    customer, 
    CONCAT_WS(', ', sorted_status) AS status_ordered
FROM 
    SortedStatus;



Hi, thank you for your help. but I get the following error: ParseException: Syntax error in line 554:undefined: ...(redemption_status AS CHAR) ORDER BY status ASC SEPARA... ^ Encountered: ) Expected: ( CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

what engine are you using?

I'm using Impala Hive

I forget about this problem , I have updated it hope it solved the issue @user15676
